# VS Setup Project - how to remove files post installation?

Tags: installation, setup-project, temporary-files, delete-file

I am creating a installer for my application using VS Setup Project. Everything works great, but the issue is, whatever files or extra DLLs I used are present in the Application folder, which I want to remove so that my folder contains only files are required by it and not by the installer. I have been searching for a way to achieve this, but I am unable to find one.

So is there any way to remove extra DLLs, text files, that were used by installer, after the installation of application. ???

*Or*

is there any special folder in which we should keep Dlls used by installer so that they are automatically removed once installation is completed or machine is restarted ???

I am really confused in this, as it looks to me a  very common requirement of removing temporary files that are only used by installer, after installation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The setup project installs whatever you added in Application Folder from File System Editor.

If you are using a project output, remove it and add your application files manually. If you added the files manually, remove the ones you don't want installed.

Comment: I have created a "temp" folder inside my Application folder for the installer files like files for custom actions, etc. So my application folder has two folders "Application" and "temp". Now after whole installation is over I want to remove this folder, but since installer is running from this temp folder itself so it is not possible while running of the installer. So I was looking for a way to remove this temp folder once my installer exits. Is there such solution??

Comment: This is not a good approach. Temporary files should be stored in Binary table and extracted during install. If you include them in your application folder, Windows Installer will manage them. So you will get a lot of unwanted behaviors. A better solution is to use a different setup authoring tools which supports temporary files.